# Sorting results based on location using elastica

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I am trying to learn ElasticSearch using elastica to connect in and finding information hard to get in order to understand how to query it.

So basically what I am trying to do is, I have inserted data into elastic search, added geo coordinates in and now what i need to do is to be able to run a query that will sort the results i get by closest to farthest.

I wanted to find all the stores in my state, then order them by which one is closest to my current location.

so given a field called "state" and field called "point" which is an array holding long/Lat using elastica what would the query be?

Thanks for any help that you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to [map](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping.html) your location field as type [`geo_point`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/geo-point-type.html) (*this needs to be done before inserting any data*)

```
{
    "stores" : {
        "properties" : {
            "point" : {
                "type" : "geo_point"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you can simply sort your search by [`_geo_distance`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort.html)

```
{
    "sort" : [
        {
            "_geo_distance" : {
                "stores.point" : [-70, 40], // <- reference starting position
                "order" : "asc",
                "unit" : "km"
            }
        }
    ],
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}
```

For Elastica, have a look at their docs regarding [mapping](http://ruflin.github.com/Elastica/#section-mapping) and [query building](http://ruflin.github.com/Elastica/#section-query), and read the unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting to sort by distance, this cut down snippet details how to use a custom score:

```
    $q = new BoolQuery();

    $subQ = new MultiMatchQuery();
    $subQ->setQuery('find me')->setFields(array('foo', 'bar'));
    $q->addShould($subQ);

    $cs = new CustomScore();

    $cs->setScript('-doc["location"].distanceInKm(lat,lon)');
    $cs->addParams(array(
        'lat' => -33.882583,
        'lon' => 151.209737
    ));

    $cs->setQuery($q);
```

Hope it helps.